# MQTT Paho Java client - inflightqos2 HashMap has 65k entries after a while

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

If I use QoS2 the subscriber needs a lot of memory due to the fact that the `inboundqos2` `HashMap` in the `ClientState` Class gets a lot of entries (peaks at 65k) after a while.

Is that normal behaviour?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/1018) appears relevant (reporting the same issue but includes more information; no response yet).